# git fetch upstream fails on gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, bitnami

I am using bitnami gitlab-6.5.1-0 version.

I created a fork for the test repo and added upstream path as shown below

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@p.q.r.s:admin/test.git (fetch)
origin  git@p.q.r.s:admin/test.git (push)
upstream    http://p.q.r.s:8085/test/test.git (fetch)
upstream    http://p.q.r.s:8085/test/test.git (push)
```

When I try to git fetch upstream I seeing following error

```
$ git fetch upstream
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing http://p.q.r.s:8085/test/test.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Not sure where I am wrong

Comment: What version of git are you using? (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1101#issuecomment-9104025, http://community.bitnami.com/t/gitlab-support-remote-push-via-https/21197/9)

Comment: Can you try with a more recent version of Git?

Comment: I had the same issue with git 1.7.1. I now use git 1.9 and it works